Need help with synthesis of iron (II,III) oxide (Fe₃O₄) nanoparticles
I am attempting to synthesize iron (II,III) oxide nanoparticles (Fe3O4). I have some iron acetate and have seen some literature where people have synthesized Cu nanoparticles using a polyol process. Using copper acetate with PVP (polyvinylpyrrolidone), DEG (diethylene glycol), and refluxing the solution. I was wondering if I can do the same to synthesize iron oxide nanoparticles maybe use PEG instead of DEG (polyethylene glycol). I also have some ferrous sulfate heptahydrate incase that can be used instead.
